# How to customize Google Apps login

Tags: google-workspace

Basically the google apps (for domains) login pages are ugly,
I wouldn't even mind if they looked like the default google ones,
But they don't so I want to know if it is possible to customize the login pages (I am aware you can change colours etc, but I want to have my own page for it)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can customize but that is not simple. Google Apps Customized Solution provider will charge you thousands of dollars for this.
This can be done using federated login which uses [SAML and SSO](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation).

Comment: That's easier said the done. Are there example's present on the internet?